# Rebol: how to write source to the clipboard?

Tags: rebol

```
f: func[][]
write clipboard:// source f
```

doesn't seem to please rebol :)

Answer (score 4):

When dealing with code, I tend to prefer SAVE over WRITE:

```
save clipboard:// :f
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the answer:

```
write clipboard:// mold :f
```